# bootstrap 3 modal in Durandal 2.0.1

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, durandal

I am using Durandal 2.0.1 and Bootstrap 3.
the problem: Modal dialog doesn't render properly. It loses css-es.
I think I need to rewrite dialog.js in durandal plugins folder. But if someone has already done it, or knows easier way to achieve this it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to convert from a 2.x to 3.0 modal
>
> - remove .hide from the .modal (it's now hidden by default) wrap
> - .modal-header .modal-body .modal-footer inside .modal-content wrap
> - .modal-content inside .modal-dialog

You need to overwrite markup in dialog.js, mainly, I think the 2nd bullet is the one you need to worry about. Starting on line 82, you should wrap three divs inside .messageBox div with one .modal-content div. Not tested tho. Please post if this worked.

```
MessageBox.defaultViewMarkup = [
        '<div data-view="plugins/messageBox" class="messageBox">',
            '<div class="modal-content">',
                '<div class="modal-header">',
                    '<h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3>',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="modal-body">',
                    '<p class="message" data-bind="text: message"></p>',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="modal-footer" data-bind="foreach: options">',
                    '<button class="btn" data-bind="click: function () { $parent.selectOption($data); }, text: $data, css: { \'btn-primary\': $index() == 0, autofocus: $index() == 0 }"></button>',
                '</div>',
             '</div>',
        '</div>'
    ].join('\n');
```

For more detailed changes needed when upgrading, [check here](http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the Durandal modal working correctly with Bootstrap 3 by overriding the Durandal CSS:

```css
.modalHost { opacity: 1 !important; }
.messageBox { visibility: visible !important; }
```